# Is there any way to have Date time other than using Date() ios

Tags: ios, swift

Hello I am working on an ios app and I need to have a reliable source of truth other than the phone date time settings (witch the user can change by himself).

It is for a situation where I do not have internet and need to timestamp an event.

I so far I tried getting timestamp from CoreLocation object -> It does takes the timeStamp of the phone.

and look in CallKit or CoreTelephony if I could get any information about the time of the cellular provider network (in case we do not have internent but are still connected to cellular networl).

Is it me or I will be forced to timestamp with whatever date I do have at the time of the event and then when internet comes back, computes the offset from my backoffice time ?

thanks

Comment: Like i said, if the user says it's 3 PM in its settings. I would like to compare it to another source. Like the Satellite GPS time (but it does not appear to be in CoreLocation public API), or the cellular provider time. Assuming of course that there is GPS Signal or at least a 2G connexion (not enouth to consider we have internet but something).

Comment: Consider using a time server, needs internet connection though

Comment: If you don't have Internet then you only have the device time. There is no other source available.

Comment: I am affraid of it. well I guess I'll have to compute the delay (if any) based on server time.

Answer (score 0):

Closing the discution. It seems that the anwser is No, there is no way to get cellular time or gps time, we do need to compute the delay based on a NTP server (or backoffice server) when we get internet back